# How can I learn about the possibilities of computational exploration for "proofs"?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I've envisioned that wouldn't it be nice if a computer could, given the assumptions of some domain (e.g. geometry or whatever) produce predictions about further statements that are valid under those assumptions or w.r.t. to other assumptions that are fulfilled or may be fulfilled by modifying some parts.

Then this should in principle allow "automatic proving of new theorems/results", right?

OTOH, I'm probably not the first person to think this.

But if I wish to understand, what are the theoretical and practical possibilities for proving and producing mathematics using computing, then what do I need to read?

Such programs could work e.g.:

- I provide the truths that are available in the context I'm in. E.g. "we have a vector space" or "we have defined dot product" or "we are in space X & we have a function with properties a,b,c".
- The program tells, what constructs are true given all the assumptions.
- The program tells, where one can extend the given facts, given that one may produce new theory by changing some assumptions. Such as "if your function had in addition properties d,e,f, then you would have ..." or "if you changed the space to Y, then you would have ...". or "if you applied transformation Z, then you would have ...".

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this on Wikipedia?
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_proof#:~:text=A%20computer-assisted%20proof%20is%20a%20mathematical%20proof%20that,verified%20using%20a%20computer%20program.%20Attempts%20have%20al](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_proof#:%7E:text=A%20computer-assisted%20proof%20is%20a%20mathematical%20proof%20that,verified%20using%20a%20computer%20program.%20Attempts%20have%20al)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't answer the question very deeply. Since I speculate that the topic possibly has some deep theoretical shortcomings. Such as that it's not possible to "predict" some things. Because the computer cannot know without assistance such links. Even when it may sound reasonable, if all mathematics was a formal system.

Comment: To design the kind of system that is asked for might require an AI greater than some smaller or previous system. I.e. a program that's $\geq$ all programs. However, that page has the useful mention of experimental mathematics that approaches this issue from numerics perspective. Since e.g. I've previously thought that "well why not treat everything as finite elements for example?" or e.g. "why not treat everything computable as a result of a finite numerical algorithm? (e.g. irrational numbers exist, since they're achievable using such algorithms)"